# Closing modal form(s) from outside and opening a new modal form

Tags: delphi

In my main form I have a button that opens a modal `Form2` (which may open other modal forms). before opening `Form2` I'm setting a timer, that will programmatically close all active modal forms (`Form2.Close`) and open a new modal `Form3`.

problem is that when `Form3` is opening modally, `Form2` remains (visible) and only when I close `Form3` by clicking the `X` will `Form2` close.

To reproduce add 3 forms to a project add a `TButton`, and drop a `TTimer` on `Form1` (main form):

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
  StdCtrls, ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private
  public
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses Unit2, Unit3;

{$R *.DFM}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := False;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := True;
  with TForm2.Create(Application) do
  try
    ShowModal;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;

procedure CloseActiveModalForms;
var
  I: Integer;
  F: TCustomForm;
  L: TList; // list of modal forms
begin
  L := TList.Create;
  try
    for I := 0 to Screen.CustomFormCount - 1 do
    begin
      F := Screen.CustomForms[I];
      if (fsModal in F.FormState) then
        L.Add(F);
    end;
    for I := 0 to L.Count - 1 do
      TCustomForm(L.Items[I]).Close; // this sets ModalResult := mrCancel
  finally
    L.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := False;
  CloseActiveModalForms; // this should close TForm2 but it does not.

  with TForm3.Create(Application) do // create new Modal TForm3
  try
    ShowModal;
  finally
    Free;
  end; 
end;

end.
```

why `Form2` is not closing? why is the `Form2` modal loop not exiting after I call `CloseActiveModalForms`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your call stack looks as follows:

```
1 Form1.Button1Click
2 Form2.ShowModal //Local message processing loop until form closes
3 Form1.Timer1Timer //Here you attempt to close the form
                    //but it doesn't actually until ShowModal exits
4 Form3.ShowModal // Another message loop that doesn't return until form closes
```

So basically, you're not able to finish the closing of Form2 until after Form3 has closed. Note that `ShowModal` is a *blocking* call to show a form. If you just `Show` Form3 (i.e. not `ShowModal`) the call doesn't block, and you'll see Form2 is able to close as the call-stack unwinds.

---

You should be able to work around this by delaying your call to show Form3 until after Form2 has closed. The OnFormDestroyEvent should suffice (unfortunately I can't test it).

```
procedure TForm1.ShowForm3(Sender: TObject);
var
  LForm: TForm;
begin
  LForm := TForm3.Create(Application); //as you created it, but nil owner should suffice
  try
    LForm.ShowModal;
  finally
    LForm.Free;
  end; 
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := False;
  //You will need to figure out how you reference the Form2 instance.
  Form2.OnFormDestroy := ShowForm3;
  CloseActiveModalForms;
  //Form2 will close after you backtrack up the call-stack.
  //When it's destroyed, your event handler will create and show a TForm3 instance.
end;
```

---

Note the above simply demonstrates the concept. You would need to devise a more robust approach depending on whatever your ultimate objective may be.

However, I would advise that excessive use of modal forms is generally considered unfriendly in terms of user experience.

Comment: `"Form1.Timer1Timer // Here you attempt to close the form but it doesn't actually until ShowModal exits"` - this is exactly my question: *why* doesn't ShowModal exists for `Form2`? The modal loop checks for `ModalResult <> 0`, and calling `Close` sets `ModalResult := mrCancel`. even if I call `Application.ProcessMessages` after calling `CloseActiveModalForms` the loop wont exit. I can't figure out why.

Comment: @zig. That is the point about Modal Forms. They suspend the activity of other forms in the process. That is why you can't click on the main form for instance - or more specifically the main form does not respond until the modal form exits. form.Close only starts the process of closing - but you show another modal form before that process can complete. So it can't complete until your new modal form closes itself.

Comment: OK, I think I got it. I failed to realize that `Timer1Timer` is actually processed **inside** the local modal message loop. So delaying the call to show `Form3` with a `PostMessage` works fine - this lets the local message loop of `Form2` to exit, and closes the modal form.

Comment: @zig - You could also add `TCustomForm(L.Items[I]).Hide;` after the `Close` call. Freeing of the modal forms would be deferred but modal result would be set if there's code that checks them in Form3. Your solution is fine however. There's no risk here since they are both user messages and have the same priority, but don't forget that `Close` also posts a message (`CM_RELEASE`).

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, Thanks. I actually added `Hide` (but before the `Close`). I'm pretty sure that `Close` does not call `Release` (by default) unless you explicitly specify a `caFree` in the close action (see `TCustomForm.CloseModal`). The `ShowModal;...finally Free;` is freeing the modal form.

Comment: @zig - Hide before Close should work too. You're right of course about caFree/Release.